# Why Does This Keep Happening To Me When I Do The Live Preview

Tags: html, css, url, brackets, filezilla

Good Morning Everyone, So basically I have Brackets And File Zila, And I'm currently working on my final project however whenever I do the live preview in Brackets to check to make sure everything shows up and works correctly the url shows up as "http://127.0.0.1:61913/index.html" and my .html are all uploaded to file zilla and I'm connected to the server so I don't what's wrong I have tried to unconnect to the server and reconnect, I made sure that all the .html files in file zila match the same ones I have in Brackets and my wwwroot folder, and that I have the same images and favicon image as I do in Brackets as well. So if someone could please help me with this that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Live preview and your uploading your files to your own unique website are 2 very different things.
The live preview address is just your own IP (be careful showing this publicly, as it can be abused)

**Live preview**: preview of whatever file you are working on, only visible by you

**Uploaded files through filezilla to your own website**: public on your website, can be accessed by anyone

Keep in mind whatever changes you make in brackets that are shown in live preview are **not** visible on your website until you upload them through filezilla.